# Multiple dates and status for same transaction

Tags: mysql, oracle, multiple-columns

```
TRANS_ID    MEMBERSHIP_NO   BUSINESS_PROCESS_NO STATUS  END_DATE         ISSUE_DATE
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1234       45678             AB                   W     1/9/2013 11:57   2-Jan-13
1234       45678             AB                   F     1/9/2013 11:59   2-Jan-13
1234       45678             AB                   P     1/10/2013 13:14  2-Jan-13
```

I have a table similar to above. I have same `trans_id` and `membership_no` and `business_process_no`, but different status and end date.

I want to be able to extract the information based on `trans_id` and `membership_no` as these are my foreign keys for other tables. But I only want one row that gives me the information based on the earliest occurrence based on `END_DATE` column:

```
TRANS_ID    MEMBERSHIP_NO   BUSINESS_PROCESS_NO STATUS  END_DATE         ISSUE_DATE
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1234       45678             AB                   W     1/9/2013 11:57   2-Jan-13
```

Thank you

Comment: This is for oracle db, mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
      SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
        FROM table_name t1
   LEFT JOIN table_name t2
          ON t2.trans_id = t1.trans_id
         AND t2.membership_no = t1.membership_no
         AND t2.end_date > t1.end_date
   LEFT JOIN table_name t3 /* Necessary when MIN(end_date) is duped */
          ON t3.trans_id = t1.trans_id
         AND t3.membership_no = t1.membership_no
         AND t3.end_date = t1.end_date
         AND t3.issue_date > t1.issue_date 
   LEFT JOIN table_name t4 /* Necessary when MIN(issue_date) is duped */
          ON t4.trans_id = t1.trans_id
         AND t4.membership_no = t1.membership_no
         AND t4.end_date = t1.end_date
         AND t4.issue_date = t1.issue_date 
         AND t4.status > t1.status  
       WHERE t1.trans_id = 1234
         AND t1.membership_no = 45678
         AND t2.trans_id IS NULL
         AND t3.trans_id IS NULL
         AND t4.trans_id IS NULL
```

This is assuming no Primary Key and I have chosen the dupe order preference myself.